# MySQL: Update all Columns With Values From A Separate Table

Tags: mysql, select

Sometimes if I want to quickly copy records from one table to another (that has the same structure) I use a query like this:

> INSERT INTO table2 SELECT * FROM
>   table1 WHERE id = SOME_VALUE

How can I add a ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE to this statement? I tried this:

> INSERT INTO SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE
>   id = 1 ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE SELECT
>   * FROM table1 WHERE id = 1

But I get an error. Is there away to accomplish the query above with out individually listing each column in the query?

P.S. Yes, I realize that it is not good practice to have multiple tables with identical structures, but sometimes you just don't get control over everything in the workplace!

Comment: Please show the structure of the tables (or the relevant parts thereof,in particular the definition of the key that cannot be duplicate), along with maybe an example of a row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below UPDATES if there is no PK duplication and INSERTs is there is:

```
REPLACE INTO table2(field1, field2, field3)
SELECT field1, field2,field3 FROM table1
WHERE id=1;
```

Comment: I'll note that's a non-Standard MySQL extension (which is why it's new to me).

Comment: Actually REPLACE deletes the record then INSERTS a new record, so if your using a timestamp for anything it will be lost

Comment: But this does answer the question +1

Answer (score 1):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html Just use the SELECT field_name from the other table like in dnagirls example